# Other functions called before jQuery.ajax() success executes

Tags: jquery

I want to get fetch some data via `jQuery.ajax()`,save this data via the success and then use it.
The order of the functions is:

```
$.ajax({
        url: this.html_url,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
              //Here the data is saved via HTML5 localStorage
        }
    });

doSomething();//The stored data is used in this function.
```

The problem is that `doSomething()` is called BEFORE the success function has saved the downloaded data. Thus, the data is being used before it has even been saved. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because `ajax` call is made `asynch`. set `async : false` in your ajax call by `default` it is `true`.

**[DOCUMENTATION](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**

```
$.ajax({    
   url: this.html_url,
   cache: false,
   async : false, // added this
   success: function(data){
     //Here the data is saved via HTML5 localStorage
   }
});
```

Second  way to call `doSomething` inside the `success`

```
success: function(data){
   //Here the data is saved via HTML5 localStorage
    doSomething()'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming i understand what you mean. Why not call `doSomething()` in your `success` callback ?

```
$.ajax({
    url: this.html_url,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
          //Here the data is saved via HTML5 localStorage
          doSomething();//The stored data is used in this function.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because AJAX calls are asyncronous. Meaning your script will not wait for them to finish before continuing (much like `setTimeout()`).

Just include your `doSomething()` function inside of the success callback.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $.ajax({
        url: this.html_url,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
              //Here the data is saved via HTML5 localStorage
        },
        async:false,
    });
    doSomething();
```